# How to enable button after using spinner

Tags: android

I am creating a program that has the mainMenuButton button (created in onCreate) disabled by default.
The user first has to check a few boxes and select something from the spinner before the mainMenuButton button becomes enabled. Currently, I can't even get the button to enable after using the spinner.

I've tried both

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
     switch(v.getId())
      {

      case R.id.main_menu_button:
          openMainMenu();
          break;

      case  R.id.building_spinner:
          Button mainMenuButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.main_menu_button); 
          mainMenuButton.setEnabled(true);
          break;
      }
    }
```

and

```
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        View mainMenuButton=(View)findViewById(R.id.main_menu_button); 
        mainMenuButton.setEnabled(true);
    }
```

but to no avail. I've also tried replacing `View` with `Button`, but that didn't enable the mainMenuButton either. What exactly am I supposed to do to enable the button after something on the spinner has been selected?

Also, would there be much of a big difference to implement it for checkboxes as well?

EDIT2 :

If I comment out the if and else statement, the button remains permanently disabled. If I leave as is, the button is never disabled to begin with and never disables, which I don't understand because I haven't even touched the spinner, so it should be disabled by default.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{

    String buildingString = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    if(buildingString !="Select Building")
    {
        Button mainMenuButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.main_menu_button); 
        mainMenuButton.setEnabled(true);
    }
    else
    {
        Button mainMenuButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.main_menu_button); 
        mainMenuButton.setEnabled(false);
    }


}
```

Im not sure if this affects it, but the spinner strings was formatted like this :

```
<string-array name="building_array">
        <item>Select Building</item>
```

Comment: `setClickable(true) ` Didn't work either

Comment: debug and check if the call back methods are triggerred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not registered a listener on  spinner.

Add this in your onCreate

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

and then write you code in onItemSelected.

Comment: I updated the post. It still doesn't disable and enable properly, although thanks that line of code does put me one step closer.

Comment: you are comparing two strings using != !! just change if(buildingString !="Select Building") to if(!buildingString.equals("Select Building"))